# Field is declared as private but I'm able to access directly

Tags: java, oop, inner-classes, anonymous-inner-class

I have a class `Foo` which extends `Dialog` (SWT).
I defined a data-member `private Bazz bazz`

Within this class I defined a method called `GetOkListener()` which basically returns an `SelectionListener` object.

Within the method `public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0)`
I am accessing to `bazz` like this: `Foo.this.bazz`.

My question is,
How is it possible? `bazz` defined as `private`.

This class is within `Foo extends Dialog`

```
@Override
protected SelectionListener GetOkListener() {

    return new SelectionListener() {

        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {

            System.out.println(CreateAlbumDialog.this.album);
        }

        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: can you paste the code instead of "code description" ?

Comment: I have a feeling that inner classes are involved here.

Comment: inner class has access to outer class private members

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an outer class called `Foo`, which has a private field called `buzz`. Within `Foo`, you are creating an *anonymous inner class*, which is implementation of `SelectionListener`.

This ***anonymous inner class*** is *non-static inner class* (by default) of `Foo`. As per the java rules, a non static inner class has access to all the fields  (including private fields) of enclosing class.

Here's the [JLS guidelines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.3) stating the same.

Answer (score 2):

Relationship between inner and outer class is that they have access to **all** their members even private ones. So Outer class has access to all members of Inner ones and Inner ones have access to Outer classes.

You also need to know that in

```
return new SelectionListener() {

    public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {

        System.out.println(CreateAlbumDialog.this.album);
    }

    public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
    }
};
```

you are creating [anonymous-**inner-class**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) which extends/implements `SelectionListener` but belongs to class which declares `GetOkListener` method (you can consider this class [local](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html) since it was declared inside method). So it is nothing special that it has access to members of outer class.

Answer (score 1):

That is because

```
new SelectionListener() {...}
```

is an *Anonymous Inner Class*. It is part of the class `Foo`, so it can access `private` fields in `Foo`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you acess to the original Bazz class. This is an inner class.